# Fontsize does not increase after changing it in event handler.

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

i found a solution for this matter but i have a difficulty in increasing the font size by giving it to a button click

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ScrollableTextBlock.FontSize < 21.5)
    {
        ScrollableTextBlock.FontSize += 1;
    }
}
```

this does not increase the text size  i'm using the same data template which is mentioned under the link:-http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what's your problem, but font size is increasing well. Here is small example:

```
public void appBarIncreaseFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page)
       {
        MainPage _page = page as MainPage;
        if (_page != null)
        {
            // example 1
            List<UIElement> buttons = _page.ContentPanel.Children.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Button)).ToList();
            foreach (var x in buttons)
            {
                Button button = x as Button;
                if (button != null && button.FontSize < 21.5)
                    button.FontSize += 1;
            }

            // example 2
            if (_page.textBlock1.FontSize < 21.5)
                _page.textBlock1.FontSize += 1;
        }
       }
```

These sample allows to increase font size of all elements of current type (button), or just concrete element font size (textblock1).

Please note, that this version uses delegates, i.e. when you create an ApplicationBar, you transefer a PhoneApplication page there and then, when you create menu items, you do it that way:

```
 ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarIncreaseFont = new ApplicationBarMenuItem("menusettings");
 appBarIncreaseFont.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                appBarIncreaseFont_Click(sender, e, page);
            };
```

If you don't know the current page, you're working at, you can't change anything on it using ApplicationBar. That's why you should use delegate here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the font size on an instantiated control. Here it looks like you are trying to increase the font size on the property of the class type itself. What you want to do is create a ScrollableTextBlock control in your .xaml file similar to this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollableTextBlock Name="scrollTxtBlk"
                         Text="Hello, World!" />

    <Button Content="Click Me!" 
            Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

and then, in your code behind file, add the click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollTxtBlk.FontSize += 1;
}
```

When you click, this should increase the font size on the ScrollableTextBlock named scrollTxtBlock, and you should see the view update with the new font size.